# Getting data from multiple tables when one table contains many rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, users, and comments.

```
Users:
id - name - email

comments:
user_id - comment - rating
```

I am trying to get all the comments for every user, but then put them into an array of this sort of structure.

```
array(
    'john' => array(
        'comment' => array(
             'text' => "had a great time thanks",
             'rating' => 5,
        )  
        'comment' => array(
             'text' => "awesome",
             'rating' => 5,
        )            
    )
    'amy' => array(
        'comment' => array(
             'text' => "it was ok",
             'rating' => 3,
        )  
        'comment' => array(
             'text' => "awesome",
             'rating' => 3,
        )            
    )
)
```

Is this possible with one sql statement? Here is my code so far

```
//get the comments
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT c.comment,
                              c.rating,
                              u.username
                    FROM comments c
                    INNER JOIN users u
                    ON c.customer_id = u.id');

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$comments = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $comments[] = array(
        'comment' => $row['comment'],
        'rating' => $row['rating'],
        'username' => $row['username']
    );
}
```

I cant think of the best way to get this structure

Answer (score 0):

Each key of an array must be unique so you cannot have multiple `comment` keys at the same level in your array.

This may be what you need:

```
$comment[$row['username']][] = array(
'comment' => $row['comment'],
'rating' => $row['rating'],
);
```